# windows 8 pinning site image -mstileimage not working

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10

I see the color is working and app name working, but not the image. If I place the image on a html element, I see it. So there is no problem with image path or rendering.

```
<meta name="application-name" content="fice.com"/>
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#515254"/>
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="original.png"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your markup is correct, so the problem must be with the path to the 'original.png' image.

Answer (score 0):

The Tile Image must be a `144x144 png` image. What is your image size ?

Source ; [Look at the Community Additions part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg491740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)